# Should i use cloned props or change props one time and make the prop into a state

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I have something similar to a UIManager and a Form, i **receive a fairly big `JSON` as props** of this component, i have to iterate over this `JSON` and assign a `onChangeFunction` to each element of this `JSON` and then render the children using this new `JSON`, i will also hold the data for all the children in a state using a something like `formData=[{ID:Value}]` and i also update the said JSON in render using this formData so the value of children are good to go (a two way binding).
**Right now i am doing this:**

```
render () {
    let newElementList = deepClone(props.elementList)

    newElementList.forEach(element => {
      if (!element.onChange) {
        element.onChange = this.onElementChange();
      }
    })

    //use newElementList from now on
}
```

**And i was wondering if i should do this instead:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    let newElementList = deepClone(props.elementList)

    newElementList.forEach(element => {
      if (!element.onChange) {
        element.onChange = this.onElementChange();
      }
    })

    this.setState({elementList: newElementList});
}

render () 
{
    //use this.state.elementList from now on
}
```

Which is the better solution ?
**Note** i also do some other changes to this `JSON` for example i update the value parameter for each element which changes and update the `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would depend on where the updates to the JSON object are happening, no?

If the JSON object passed through props is just an arbitrary starting point for the component, then placing it in state on mount should suit your purposes so long as all the updates originate from this component and/or its children.

If the JSON data is being manipulated by an ancestor of this component, however, then this solution won't work since state would be set only when the component mounts, and the component would fail to reflect any changes. In that case, you'd want to continue putting together the element list in render (if you don't expect other changes to trigger a render) or in componentDidUpdate (if the component will rerendering often and you don't want to process the JSON every time).